# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, javafx, jar, classnotfoundexception

I try to compress my javafx app into jar, and when i run:

`java -jar /home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds_global/j/fileToClip/build/libs/server-1.0.jar -cp /home/roroco/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar`

it raise this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I'm sure jfxrt.jar include javafx.application.Application

```
roroco@roroco /tmp/fileToClip $ jar tf 
/home/roroco/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar|gr Application\.class
com/sun/glass/ui/Application.class
com/sun/glass/ui/gtk/GtkApplication.class
javafx/application/Application.class
```

why it will raise "ClassNotFoundException"?

**update**

my java version is:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/try/j/try $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify that jar file on the classpath: jar files in the `lib/ext` folder are on the class path by default. Are you certain that `java` is pointing to that jdk version (what does `java -version` give?).

Comment: @James_D even i remove -cp, the error still be raised, I hope a way to fix it

Comment: Which JDK version are you running with?

Comment: @James_D, thx, I find the reason, since i use openjdk not oracle jdk, when switch to oracle jdk, everything work

Answer (score 2):

I find the reason: since my java version is:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/try/j/try $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

i should use oracle bin/java instead, in my case, I use following will work:

```
/home/roroco/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java -jar /home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds_global/j/fileToClip/build/libs/server-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably de java version in your IDE is not the same that the java version of your linux when you "java" comamnd.